# SQLite C# query doesn' t work

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, nvarchar

I'm having trouble executing a query from C# to the SQLite DB, I use the following query and it gives me the error that something is wrong at: "max".

```
create table ClockMessages (ID int identity(1, 1) primary key, InsertDateTime DateTime not null, SendDateTime DateTime, Data nvarchar(max));
```

Can't I use the `nvarchar` format, and should I use `TEXT` instead?

Comment: What is the exact difference? Can I still store a "max" amount of characters in a text field?\

Comment: Please update your title with your specific question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TEXT!
you can read [here](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) more about sqlite datatypes

**TEXT**=>The value is a text string, stored using the database encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).

> SQLite uses a more general dynamic type system. In SQLite, the
>   datatype of a value is associated  with the value itself, not with its
>   container. The dynamic type system of SQLite is backwards  compatible
>   with the more common static type systems of other database engines in
>   the sense that  SQL statement that work on statically typed databases
>   should work the same way in SQLite. However,  the dynamic typing in
>   SQLite allows it to do things which are not possible in traditional
>   rigidly  typed databases.

**That noted:**

> SQLite does not impose any length restrictions (other than the large
>   global SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH limit) on the length of strings, BLOBs or
>   numeric values.

**Finally:**

Maximum length of a string or BLOB

> The maximum number of bytes in a string or BLOB in SQLite is defined
>   by the preprocessor macro SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH. The default value of this
>   macro is 1 billion (1 thousand million or 1,000,000,000). You can
>   raise or lower this value at compile-time using a command-line option
>   like this:
>
> -DSQLITE_MAX_LENGTH=123456789 The current implementation will only
>   support a string or BLOB length up to 231-1 or 2147483647. And some
>   built-in functions such as hex() might fail well before that point. In
>   security-sensitive applications it is best not to try to increase the
>   maximum string and blob length. In fact, you might do well to lower
>   the maximum string and blob length to something more in the range of a
>   few million if that is possible.
>
> During part of SQLite's INSERT and SELECT processing, the complete
>   content of each row in the database is encoded as a single BLOB. So
>   the SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH parameter also determines the maximum number of
>   bytes in a row.
>
> The maximum string or BLOB length can be lowered at run-time using the
>   sqlite3_limit(db,SQLITE_LIMIT_LENGTH,size) interface.

Answer (score 1):

use `TEXT`.

According to the manual,

`TEXT` - The value is a text string, stored using the database encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).

- [SQLite Datatype](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Comment: this is the second table I added, by the first table I did use nvarchar(32) etc and that just worked out fine, should I use text also at that query now?

Answer (score 1):

*SQLite* doesn't use sizes when declaring the `varchar` type.

From **[FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q9)**

> (9) What is the maximum size of a VARCHAR in SQLite?
>
> SQLite **doesn't enforce the length** of a VARCHAR. You can declare a
>   **VARCHAR(10)** and SQLite will be happy to let you put 500 characters in
>   it. And it will keep all 500 characters intact - **it never truncates**.

You can use `TEXT` type instead of. Check out from **[here](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)**.

> TEXT. The value is a text string, stored using the database encoding
>   (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).

Answer (score 1):

There are only 5 datatypes in SQLite.

when you use some of these

```
CHARACTER(20)
VARCHAR(255)
VARYING CHARACTER(255)
NCHAR(55)
NATIVE CHARACTER(70)
NVARCHAR(100)
TEXT
CLOB
```

in create table statement, SQLite transforms it to `Text`

also

> Note that numeric arguments in parentheses that following the type
>   name (ex: "VARCHAR(255)") are ignored by SQLite - SQLite does not
>   impose any length restrictions (other than the large global
>   SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH limit) on the length of strings, BLOBs or numeric
>   values.

[SQLite data types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)